# Aliasing accesses through a std::bit_cast()ed pointer

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, strict-aliasing

Violating strict-aliasing rules yields undefined behavior, e.g. when sending a struct over the network into a char buffer, and then that char pointer is C-style/`std::reinterpret_cast()` casted to a struct pointer.

The C++ [`std::bit_cast()` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast) looks like it could be used to cast such pointers in an (implementation?) defined way, i.e. without violating strict-aliasing rules.

Example:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

#include <bit>

int get_sock_addr(const struct sockaddr *a)
{
    struct sockaddr_in *x = std::bit_cast<struct sockaddr_in*>(a);
    return x->sin_addr.s_addr;
}
```

So the caller of `get_sock_addr()` somehow obtained a `sockaddr` pointer and has determined that it actually points to a `sockaddr_in` struct.

So, is such pointer casting via `std::bit_cast()` a valid use-case?

Or does it somehow yield undefined behavior, as well?

If it's defined behavior, does the standard classify such pointer-casting as implementation-defined behavior?

---

The [`std::bit_cast()` proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0476r1.html) mentions:

> If no value representation corresponds to To's object representation then the returned value is unspecified.

So is a standard-conforming compiler possible where different pointer representations are incompatible such that they can't correspond to each other?

Comment: Your example, with its assumptions, is the standard, valid use case for `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: @DavisHerring hm, it really depends on what is done with the sockaddr pointer before/after calling the example get_sock_addr function, right? For example, with something like `sockaddr *a = getfromsomewhere(); if (a->sa_family == AF_INET) addr = get_sock_addr(a); ... } ...` the sockaddr_in object is accessed via 2 aliasing pointers of types which aren't covered by the strict-aliasing rules, correct?

Comment: In the question you simply said “it actually points to a `sockaddr_in` struct”.  The code you just gave tries to validate that assumption but is actually incompatible with it (unfortunately, since this is how traditional C interfaces are designed).  The common-initial-subsequence rules are meant to allow this sort of tagging, but they require an actual union.

Comment: @DavisHerring well, in the question I said that the caller 'has determined that it actually points to a sockaddr_in struct'. So the code I gave in my last comment is one possible implementation of this determination step. Sure, including that step in the original example code would have made a better example for the purpose of the question, arguably.

Comment: We are in violent agreement.  That code is the obvious means of determining the actual type hidden behind the pointer—but C++ doesn’t allow you to do that, since it involves using the object as a different type to make that very determination.

Comment: @maxschlepzig: Is there any indication of if/when the authors of Standards decided that programmers should jump through hoops to accomplish things that could easily be done via pointer casts in pre-standard C, versus merely intending that implementations not be required to support such constructs *in cases where their customers wouldn't need them*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting the pointer value is irrelevant. What matters is the object. You have a pointer to an object of type X, but the pointer's type is Y. Trying to access the object of type X through a pointer/reference to unrelated type Y is where the UB comes from.

How you obtained those pointers is mostly irrelevant. So `bit_cast` is no better than `reinterpret_cast` in this regard.

If there is no `sockaddr_in` there, then you can't pretend that there is one. However, it's possible that [implicit object creation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object) in C++20 already solves this matter, depending on your code. If it does, then it *still* doesn't matter how you get the pointer.

Comment: Good point about object creation. Wondered some time ago why I couldn't find the C effective types concept in a C++11 standards document.