# Given two objects of different types and their relative location in memory, can I derive a pointer to one object from a pointer to the other?

Tags: c++, pointers, language-lawyer, c++20, c++23

In the following example, we have two objects that are of different types but happen to be located right next to each other in memory.

```cpp
struct X {
    alignas(long) int val = 1;
};

struct Y {
    long val = 2;
};

[...]

std::byte* buf = new std::byte[sizeof(X) + sizeof(Y)];
X* x = new (buf) X();
new (buf + sizeof(X)) Y();
```

Given `x`, and our knowledge of where the instance of `Y` is actually located in memory relative to `x`, is there any way to derive a pointer to the instance of `Y` from `x` that complies with C++20 or C++23?

In other words, is the following code standards compliant, or is there any way to make it standards compliant:

```cpp
Y* y = std::launder(reinterpret_cast<Y*>(reinterpret_cast<std::byte*>(x) + sizeof(X)));
y->val = 3;
```

I suspect the code is not standards compliant in either C++20 or C++23 for a couple of reasons:

(1) [P1839R5](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p1839r5.pdf) indicates that it isn't actually possible to obtain a usable pointer to an object representation in the first place.

(2) Even given the revised pointer arithmetic rules from P1839R5, it still seems like you wouldn't be able to go from a pointer to one object representation to a different object representation.

Comment: `std::bit_cast`?

Comment: As far as I know (could be wrong), comparing two pointers is only valid if they refer to to the same object.

Comment: This should be legal.  `x` and `buf` point to the same address, and `reinterpret_cast<std::byte*>(x) + sizeof(X)` would be valid indexing into `buf`

Comment: `reinterpret_cast<std::byte*>(x)` points to `x`, and not the first byte of the buffer, since `X` is not pointer-interconvertible with `std::byte[]`. You would want something like `auto& byte_buf = *std::launder(reinterpret_cast<std::byte(*)[sizeof(X)+sizeof(Y)]>(x)); Y* y = std::launder(reinterpret_cast<Y*>(byte_buf + sizeof(X));`. But I suspect that the first launder is not allowed because more bytes are reachable. And since it appears that the bytes after the X object are literally described as "not reachable", that may be your answer

Comment: @PaulSanders, by `std::bit_cast`, do you mean what I've proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76113351/given-two-objects-of-different-types-and-their-relative-location-in-memory-can#comment134234419_76114334)?

Comment: @MichaelKourlas Yes

Comment: If you can convert your pointers to `uintptr_t`'s, then you can do any sort of math you want on those, then convert back to pointers again when desired and (assuming you didn't mess up the math) have valid pointers again.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Yes, but the resulting behaviour is implementation-defined and may not do what you want. For example, GCC's documentation explicitly states that "[the resulting pointer must reference the same object as the original pointer, otherwise the behavior is undefined](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Arrays-and-pointers-implementation.html)".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no way to do that. (Except maybe with the help of implicit object creation of a suitable aggregate type, see my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76115421/does-implicit-object-creation-circumvent-reachability-conditions-of-stdlaunder).)

`std::launder` specifically has a precondition that it won't make any bytes reachable that wouldn't be reachable from the original pointer via `reinterpret_cast` and pointer arithmetic inside arrays.

With `reinterpret_cast` only objects which are pointer-interconvertible from one another can be reached without `std::launder`, but in particular neither the `std::byte` object, nor the `std::byte` array object at the same address as the `X` object are pointer-interconvertible with the `X` object. (See [[basic.compound]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.compound#4).) Therefore a pointer to the underlying array (elements) cannot be obtained without `std::launder` and using `std::launder` is impossible due to its precondition.

Specifically, the addition in `reinterpret_cast<std::byte*>(x) + sizeof(X)` has undefined behavior because `reinterpret_cast<std::byte*>(x)` points to the `X` object, not a `std::byte` object, and so [[expr.add]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.add#6) is violated. Adding `std::launder` is impossible due to its precondition.

The linked paper attempts to properly specify access to object representations, which hasn't actually been specified in the way it is used in practice (e.g. by casting to `unsigned char*`), but only via `memcpy`/`std::bit_cast` to a suitable buffer. If it is specified, I would expect it to be in a way that shouldn't be able to work around the reachability precondition placed on `std::launder`, which seems to make it impossible to reach the `Y` object from the `X` object in your example intentionally. It should be possible to access only the object representation of the `X` object itself from a pointer to it, not the object representations of the underlying array or the `Y` object.

Comment: What about using `std::bit_cast` to get an actual pointer to the original `std::byte` array from the pointer to `X`? In other words, would `std::launder(reinterpret_cast<Y*>(std::bit_cast<std::byte*>(x) + sizeof(X)))` work?

Comment: There was some discussion about using `std::bit_cast` with pointers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67765898/aliasing-accesses-through-a-stdbit-casted-pointer). The conclusion was that this could not be used for type punning since no object of the destination pointer type actually existed at that address. In this case, I am not sure whether the `std::byte` array still exists after the placement-new calls for `X` and `Y`, but if it does, it seems like it could work.

Comment: @MichaelKourlas Per https://eel.is/c++draft/bit.cast#2.sentence-6 `std::bit_cast<std::byte*>(x)` could produce any value consistent with the value representation. This could be a pointer value pointing to the `std::byte` element of the array or a pointer value still pointing to the `X` object, assuming they have the same value representation in the implementation. So it seems to still be UB to me. (Although that seems inconsistent with https://eel.is/c++draft/basic#types.general-4.sentence-4 which I read to allow only one value per value representation for pointers.)

Comment: @MichaelKourlas There is one way I see being able to access the `Y` object from the `X` one (but not the other way around), although it doesn't really seem intended to me. See my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76115421/does-implicit-object-creation-circumvent-reachability-conditions-of-stdlaunder).

Comment: Since the value returned is unspecified I think it would be implementation-defined behaviour rather than strictly UB, but certainly not guaranteed by the standard. It really is a shame there isn't an `std::launder`-like function to do this.

Comment: @MichaelKourlas For a given input a program effectively has UB if any execution path permitted by unspecified behavior on an instance of the abstract machine has undefined behavior. See https://eel.is/c++draft/intro.abstract#3 and https://eel.is/c++draft/intro.abstract#5.sentence-2. In contrast _implementation-defined behavior_ determines parameters of the abstract machine and thereby the instance of the abstract machine. See https://eel.is/c++draft/intro.abstract#2.