# Does implicit object creation circumvent reachability conditions of std::launder?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, reinterpret-cast, stdlaunder

This question results from thinking about my answer in [Given two objects of different types and their relative location in memory, can I derive a pointer to one object from a pointer to the other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76113351/given-two-objects-of-different-types-and-their-relative-location-in-memory-can).

My assumption was that the standard currently allows, under the assumption that `sizeof(int) == sizeof(float)`, `alignof(int) == alignof(float)` and `sizeof(int) == alignof(int)`, to optimize the function `g` in

```
void f(float*);

int g() {
    alignas(int) std::byte storage[sizeof(int)*2];
    auto x = new(storage) float();
    auto y = new(storage + sizeof(float)) int();
    f(x);
    return *y;
}
```

to always return `0`, because it is impossible to reach the `int` object from the `float` object due to the reachability precondition on `std::launder`. As far as I can tell no current compiler actually does this though.

However, suppose `f` was defined like this:

```
struct A {
    float x;
    int y;
};

void f(float* x) {
    reinterpret_cast<A*>(x)->y = 1;
}
```

assuming `sizeof(A) == 2*sizeof(int)` and `alignof(A) == alignof(int)` on the implementation.

Doesn't `f` then have well-defined behavior, so that the optimization is impossible, because implicit object creation when the lifetime of `storage` begins can create an `A` object of which the `int` and `float` objects would become member subobjects and for which the `float` object is pointer-interconvertible with the `A` object?

Am I misunderstanding the intended optimization benefit of the `std::launder` reachability precondition or is implicit object creation from C++20 just messing it up? Is it supposed to apply only to non-standard-layout types?

Also see my related question [std::launder vs placement-new reachability condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70807452/stdlaunder-vs-placement-new-reachabibility-condition).

Comment: During implicit-lifetime object addition discussion I remember smth. about that now one has to consistently compare 2 implicitly-created, say, `int`s, because in some TU there can be a type having them as member subobjects. I think your example is somewhat similar.