# How can I access a second disparate object in the same over-sized allocated given only a pointer to the first?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, placement-new

Consider the following.

```
struct T { int a = 1; };
struct U { char b = 2; };
static_assert(alignof(U) == 1);

// Allocate storage.  Cast via P0593 to access implicit array of unsigned char.
auto* s = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(::operator new(sizeof(T) + sizeof(U)));

// Place T and U in that storage.
T* t = new (s) T;
U* u = new (s + sizeof(T)) U;

// Is there a legal way to get a pointer to `u` given only `t` and not `s`?
U* u2 = reinterpret_cast<U*>(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(t) + sizeof(T));
```

The question: Is there a way, given only `t` to get `u`?

I know I can `std::launder()` `s` to get `t`, and presumably I can `std::launder()` `s + sizeof(T)` to get `u`. But, if all I have is `t`, is there a way?

I know that `std::launder()` has requirements about "reachability", so I don't think it can be part of the solution since `u` is not reachable from `t`.

I know that if I put T and U together in a struct, things are different, but that's not the case I am interested in.  (Consider that U might actually be of dynamic size.)

I think my question boils down to: How do I recover `s` (the underlying *complete* storage) from `t`?  I know I can get the object representation of the object at `t`, but I don't think that's the same as `s` because it's only `sizeof(T)` long, right?

If I want to allocate once and store these non-array disparate objects, am I forced to store a pointer to `u` inside `t` just to recover it later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are saying `std::launder` has a precondition that explicit prohibits this. It seems intended to be impossible.

There are a few other constructs in the language that can make more bytes reachable than should be possible by this precondition, see e.g. my questions [std::launder vs placement-new reachability condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70807452/stdlaunder-vs-placement-new-reachability-condition) and [Does implicit object creation circumvent reachability conditions of std::launder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76115421/does-implicit-object-creation-circumvent-reachability-conditions-of-stdlaunder).

However, given that these restrictions were explicitly added to `std::launder`, I suspect that them not being applied to these other constructs as well is the defect and not the other way around.

---

I do not know whether there is any compiler that actually makes use of this reachability restriction for optimization though.

Comment: Despite much searching, I didn't find https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76113351 which does seem to be essentially the same question.  (Although in my case the storage array is implicitly created.)

Comment: If your answer is correct, does this imply that the old C trick of having a "header struct" followed by dynamically-sized "spill over" data has no analogue in C++20?  Doesn't this mean you can never get to such "extra bytes" after the struct without storing a pointer to them?  (Sorry if this is a separate question.)

Comment: @BradSpencer You can still store a pointer to the underlying storage at which the header starts and launder it when accessing the header. But otherwise, I guess yes. Unfortunately I have yet to find any discussion of the intentions behind this precondition. It was added together with a rewrite of how pointer values work in general with C++17 and the paper introducing the changes doesn't contain any discussion. Presumably it should enable compilers to optimize under the assumption that such tricks are _not_ applied, but I don't think any compiler actually assumes that given C compatibility.

Comment: @BradSpencer The implementation of functions like `std::make_unique` will typically use a similar trick. But of course, the implementation of this function can use non-standard tricks, or exploit known behavior of the specific compiler.

Comment: @JamesKanze What would `std::make_unique` need that trick for? Also, it can't rely on such tricks, because since C++23 it must be usable in constant expressions where UB is prohibited. Therefore it can't even use `reinterpret_cast` in its implementation (at least the `if consteval` path).

Comment: Perhaps he means `std::make_shared()`, how it allocates the control block at the same time as the object?  Except in that case, doesn't the `shared_ptr` store separate pointers to the control block and the object?  I think that means it would never need to find one pointer from the other.

Comment: @BradSpencer Yes, I don't think `make_shared` needs that either. Because the control block might need to refer to some external allocation anyway (which happens if a `std::shared_ptr(new ...)` is used instead), there must already be space for an extra pointer. Even if that was not the case, as I mentioned above, one can always store a pointer to the underlying storage and launder it on use.

Comment: Yes, I meant `std::make_shared`. Although the standard doesn't require it, the whole point of ``std::make_shared` is that there can normally be just one allocation for both the counter/destructor and the the object itself. And since the implementation of `std::make_shared` is part of the implementation, and not user code, it is free to use anything the implementation provided, including undefined behavior that "happens" to work in the implementation. (Typically, the implementation will put pointers to both elements in the `shared_ptr` object itself.)