# std::bit_cast equivalent for CUDA device side code?

Tags: cuda, constexpr, type-punning

I have a couple of "magic"¹ floating point constants, which I want to use bit-exact in CUDA device side computation, in the form of `constexpr` symbols. On the host side you'd use `std::bit_cast<float>(0x........)` for that. However NVCC doesn't "like" `std::bit_cast` in device side code.

In GLSL you'd use `intBitsToFloat`, however I see no built-in function in the CUDA C++ language extensions that can do this.

---

1: well, they're not that "magic", basically they're the floating point equivalent of 0.999…·2ⁿ, that is all bits of the mantissa set to `1` with `-(n+1)` added to exponent "0" (i.e. `0x7E-n-1`).

Comment: Reinterpretcast from unsigned int to float? Or better, simple memcpy

Comment: Yeah, `reinterpret_cast` seems to work for type-punning in CUDA (not sure if the compiler just doesn't use the strict aliasing rule in the absence of `__restrict__` or if I just haven't seen a case where it can fail), but the correct/secure C++ way is using `memcpy`. In my experience the compiler is able to avoid the actual `memcpy` so one doesn't have to worry about performance.

Comment: But I admit that none of those two methods is suited for initializing a `constexpr float` which is probably what you are looking for? In this case aliasing (of a literal) isn't really a problem either.

Comment: I recommend writing a [CCCL](https://github.com/NVIDIA/cccl) issue to communicate to the libcu++ devs that `cuda::std::bit_cast` would be welcome.

Comment: @paleonix I'm well aware of the `memcpy` way. But I'm explicit interested in a `constexpr` way. For what it's worth, I intend to pass that value by means of a template parameter (which only supports integer types).

Comment: @paleonix yeah, I've ssen that `--expt-relaxed-constexpr` suggestion message by NVCC, but the wording it comes with carries a big *Here be Dragons* vibe.

Comment: Can you show example code? can't you just declare the constexpr floats outside of the kernel?

Comment: I tried to add some context to my answer with regard to the "experimental-ness" of `--expt-relaxed-constexpr`. I think the more interesting question is why this hasn't become the default (yet) or in what kind of edge case could making this the default break old code.

Comment: @AbatorAbetor well, strictly speaking I want this to automatically deduce the value from a template type. To make a long story short, mapping a full integer range to floating point range [0, 1] by simply using a factor of `1./0xF…` is not ideal. What you actually want to do is mapping to the "open" range [0, 1( – ideally you'd do this by padding the low bits with the LSB of the subnormal during normalization. It's a pet peeve of mine, that int→normalized float conversion isn't part of any ISA, despite its implementation in HW being shockingly trivial.

Answer (score 3):

Given a **host** compiler that supports it, you can use `std::bit_cast` in CUDA C++20 **device** code (i.e. CUDA >=12) to initialize a `constexpr` variable. You just need to tell nvcc to make it possible by passing [`--expt-relaxed-constexpr`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#expt-relaxed-constexpr-expt-relaxed-constexpr).

This flag is labeled as an "Experimental flag", but to me it sounds more like "this flag might be removed/renamed in a future release" than a "here be dragons" in terms of its results. It is also already quite old, which gives me some confidence. See the [CUDA 8.0 nvcc docs](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/archive/8.0/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#options-for-altering-compiler-linker-behavior) from 2016 (docs for even older versions are not available online as html, so I didn't check further back).

As `constexpr` code is evaluated by the compiler on the host independent of the surrounding device context, I would not expect this flag to be some brittle "black magic". It just needs to pass off the evaluation to the host compiler and use the resulting value/object.

Given all this context I would rather expect the `--expt-relaxed-constexpr`-behavior to become the default in some future CUDA version than it vanishing without a replacement.

For anyone who needs a non-`constexpr` version of `bit_cast`, see [Safe equivalent of std::bit_cast in C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67521312/10107454) (just add `__device__`).

Answer (score 2):

In CUDA `__device__` code there is an intrinsic function `__int_as_float`, as well as `__float_as_int` which does what you need. The only limitation is that it is not `constexpr`.

As a walkaround, I believe you could keep the `constexpr` value as an integer and call `__int_as_float` only at the spot where you transition into the run-time that executes on GPU.

Comment: While I like learning about intrinsics, there doesn't seem to be any advantage compared to a custom `bit_cast` (using `memcpy`) as implemented in the Q&A linked at the end of my answer that is also more general in terms of types. Or do these intrinsics somehow produce even better code?

Comment: One would have to compare the produced code to be certain, but in general CUDA "hates" taking addresses of local variables (or doing memcpy). As long as variable is in a register, it is fast and efficient, but if an address is needed the variable lands in local memory (which is in global or cache). It may happen that compiler figures out that `bit_cast` and `memcpy` can be resolved without actually touching memory, but you need to check the assembly to be certain. `--ptxas-options=-v` nvcc option may also give a hint how many registers and how much local memory is actually used.

Comment: @paleonix `__int_as_float` I am fairly certain it produces no code as all. Just informs that given content of a register should be now treated as a float.

Comment: The point is that compilers will do the same (i.e. nothing) for `memcpy`. I tried it before on Compiler Explorer with nvcc.

Comment: @paleonix If that is the case in your use case - go for it! I am not sure it will work in all possible cases - sometimes compiler can get lost on the programmer's intend - so this is something you have to monitor.